# Magento 1.9 : how to ovrride in lib/Zend folder inside currency.php file

Tags: overrides, lib, magento1.9.3.7

Override Magento root folder In lib/Zend/currency.php file possible or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy this file and move to `app/code/local/Zend/currency.php` this path

then local code pool file will be called instead of lib file

this is the only way to override lib folder files

Comment: now it's working thanks for reply. @Murtuza Zabuawala

Comment: @RavindrasinhZala you are always welcome :)